# How to not return a readonly array in numba objmode?

Tags: python-3.x, numba

**Problem:**
I have a `NumbaPerformanceWarning` about the use of non-contiguous arrays when using objmode in nopython mode, as it seems to return a view of the objects.

Bellow is a small code to reproduce my problem:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, objmode
from scipy.linalg import expm

@njit
def foo(A, b):
    # created contiguous
    G_t = np.zeros(shape=A.shape, dtype=np.float64)

    with objmode(G_t="float64[:, :]"):
        G_t += expm(A)
        # When uncommented -> still a NumbaPerformanceWarning
        # G_t = np.ascontiguousarray(G_t)

    # When uncommented -> no more NumbaPerformanceWarning
    # G_t = np.ascontiguousarray(G_t)
    return G_t @ b

N = 4
A = np.random.random(size=(N, N))
b = np.random.random(size=(N))
foo(A, b)
# NumbaPerformanceWarning: '@' is faster on contiguous arrays, called on (array(float64, 2d, A), readonly array(float64, 1d, C))
# return G_t @ b
```

**Question:**
Is my use of `objmode` wrong? Is there a clean way to prevent this performance warning?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`float64[:, :]` means a view that is not mandatory contiguous while `float64[:, ::1]` is always contiguous. Thus, using the second one make the code faster and removes the warning here. Note that doing the `+=` in the `objmode` section is not the most efficient solution. You extract the array created in the section and to the `+=` after that.

```
with objmode(tmp="float64[:, ::1]"):
    tmp = expm(A)
G_t += tmp
```

This solution is 20% faster than just adding `::1` (which nearly do not improves performance because Numpy do not use Numba typing information).